# Dispatching and handling an event from an ANE (Air Native Extension) to a flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex

The explanation of my problem requires some background info making the question a little long, so bear with me.

An ANE (Air Native Extension) consists of 3 parts, the native code that allows you to use device specific features (I'm using android), the actionscript library that accesses those native code functions and makes them available for the Flex mobile application, and the Flex mobile application.

For my ANE, I'm getting internet info in the onReceive() method that I extend from broadcast receiver. Now that method doesn't return anything, so when it's done I store it in a global variable and dispatch an event saying that the info is ready.

The actionscript interface listens for this event and when it receives it, it updates a global variable and then also dispatches an event telling the flex mobile app that the info is ready.

So when the flex mobile app learns that the info it needs is ready it goes in and gets it.

Here's an example of how I coded it if the explanation wasn't clear enough:

```
NATIVE CODE:
public MyClass(AnotherClass v,FREContext c){
    this.v = v;
    this.c = c;       //Will use c to dispatch event
}
onReceive(){
    ....code....
    String x = "internet info"
    AnotherClass.setGlobalVar(x);
    c.dispatchStatusEventAsync("status", "internetInfoReady");
}


ACTIONSCRIPT INTERFACE CODE:
private var context:ExtensionContext;
var info:String;
public function Interface(){
    context = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("id",null);
    context.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,onStatus);
}

public function scan():void{
    //calls function that runs asynchronously to get internet info
}
public function onStatus(event:StatusEvent):void{
    if((event.level == "status") && (event.code="internetInfoReady")){
        info=String(context.all("getInfo"));  //function that retrieves value x in AnotherClass and returns it
        dispatchEvent(new Event("internetInfoReady"));
    }

}

public function getInfo():String{
    return info;
}


FLEX MOBILE APP CODE:
<s:View ....
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        var a:Interface = new Interface();

        protected function getInfo(event:MouseEvent):void{
            a.scan();
            test.addEventListener("internetInfoReady",onGetInfo);
        }

        protected function onGetInfo(evt:Event):void{
            var info:String = "";
            if(evt.type == "internetInfoReady"){
                info = a.getInfo();
                a.toast(info);  //function that calls android built in toast commands
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button left="251" right="250" top="40" height="43" label="Get Info" click="getInfo(event)"
          fontFamily="Arial" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

The app isn't running on my device and I just want to make sure that I'm dispatching the events right. I created an android app that uses the native code already written to display the information gotten on the screen so I can make sure that part works, and it does so I know that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your as3 interface class must **`extends EventDispatcher`**.
I notices one strange thing in case custom event in extension project

```
dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CONSTANT, someData));
```

does not fire event, but

```
var ce:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CONSTANT);
    ce.data = someData;
    dispatchEvent(ce);
```

works fine